# Spring Security JavaConfig with HTTP Basic and JSR-250: 403 Forbidden

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsr250

How the Configuration should look like when using `@RolesAllowed` Annotation?
I don't need any auth at my webpage as there's no login or anything else. Only the admin panel should have an http basic auth.

This is my current code:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("production");
        rootContext.scan("com.xxx.config");

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", DispatcherServlet.class);
        servlet.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

        FilterRegistration charEncodingfilterReg = container.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
        charEncodingfilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
        charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("admin")
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public class AdminController {
    // ...
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().realmName(env.getProperty("adminRealm"));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Output: DEBUG SecurityConfig - Register credentials for roles user, admin: admin:admin
        log.debug("Register credentials for roles user, admin: " + env.getProperty("adminUsername") + ":" + env.getProperty("adminPassword"));
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(env.getProperty("adminUsername")).password(env.getProperty("adminPassword")).roles("user", "admin");
    }
}
```

But after the login with the correct credentials I'm just getting a HTTP 403.

Log while requesting the admin panel:

```
DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@80a4fdc5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin,ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 5973DDB69FFF44B3B9AD6077DFD7B1ED; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css]
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Taking snapshot of request attributes before include
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css]
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css] are [/resources/**]
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css] are {}
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@2f096210] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css] is: -1
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css] against base location: ServletContext resource [/resources/**]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Found matching resource: ServletContext resource [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Determined media type 'text/css' for ServletContext resource [/resources/webjars/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css]
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Restoring snapshot of request attributes after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.introspectTypeLevelMapping] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.FLASH_MAP_MANAGER] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.THEME_SOURCE] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.THEME_RESOLVER] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.CONTEXT] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.pathWithinHandlerMapping] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.OUTPUT_FLASH_MAP] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.bestMatchingPattern] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Removing attribute [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER] after include
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Applying processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016
DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Applying processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016
DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Applying processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016
DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Applying processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016
DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Applying processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016
DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Applying processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016
DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Skipping processor: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016
DEBUG BenchmarkProcessorDecorator - StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 0
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00000  �  Using ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.css.LessCssProcessor@2377a016

DEBUG ProcessorDecorator - Applying processor: ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.impl.css.CssUrlRewritingProcessor@76ec1185
...much wro4j stuff...
DEBUG BenchmarkProcessorDecorator - StopWatch '': running time (millis) = 2770
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
02770  100%  Using ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.impl.css.JawrCssMinifierProcessor@2c8e5aa6

DEBUG DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator - found content: .clearfix{*zoom:1}.clearfix...
DEBUG DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator - Content to fingerprint: [.clearfix{*zoom:1}.clearfix...]
DEBUG AbstractDigesterHashStrategy - SHA1HashStrategy hash: 51eda04c354d73243fa387841c9d888bbeb4a201
DEBUG DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator - computed entry: hash: 51eda04c354d73243fa387841c9d888bbeb4a201
DEBUG ResourceBundleProcessor - ETag hash detected: "51eda04c354d73243fa387841c9d888bbeb4a201". Sending 304 status code
DEBUG WroFilter - Disable Cache is true. Destroying model...
DEBUG DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator - Destroy model
DEBUG DefaultResourceAuthorizationManager - clear.
DEBUG DefaultResourceAuthorizationManager - clear.
DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@80a4fdc5: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@80a4fdc5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin,ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 5973DDB69FFF44B3B9AD6077DFD7B1ED; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@51879f03
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/resources/img/logo.png'; against '/logout'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@80a4fdc5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin,ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 5973DDB69FFF44B3B9AD6077DFD7B1ED; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/logo.png reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/resources/img/logo.png]
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/img/logo.png
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/img/logo.png]
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/img/logo.png] are [/resources/**]
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/img/logo.png] are {}
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/img/logo.png] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@2f096210] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/resources/img/logo.png] is: -1
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [img/logo.png] against base location: ServletContext resource [/resources/**]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Found matching resource: ServletContext resource [/resources/img/logo.png]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Determined media type 'image/png' for ServletContext resource [/resources/img/logo.png]
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@80a4fdc5: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@80a4fdc5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin,ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 5973DDB69FFF44B3B9AD6077DFD7B1ED; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@51879f03
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/resources/img/eagle.png'; against '/logout'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@80a4fdc5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin,ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 5973DDB69FFF44B3B9AD6077DFD7B1ED; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/img/eagle.png reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/resources/img/eagle.png]
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/img/eagle.png
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@80a4fdc5: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@80a4fdc5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin,ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 5973DDB69FFF44B3B9AD6077DFD7B1ED; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@51879f03
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff'; against '/logout'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/img/eagle.png]
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/img/eagle.png] are [/resources/**]
DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@80a4fdc5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin,ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 5973DDB69FFF44B3B9AD6077DFD7B1ED; Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user'
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/img/eagle.png] are {}
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/img/eagle.png] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@2f096210] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/resources/img/eagle.png] is: -1
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [img/eagle.png] against base location: ServletContext resource [/resources/**]
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Found matching resource: ServletContext resource [/resources/img/eagle.png]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Determined media type 'image/png' for ServletContext resource [/resources/img/eagle.png]
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff]
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff] are [/resources/**]
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff] are {}
DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@2f096210] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff] is: -1
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff] against base location: ServletContext resource [/resources/**]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Found matching resource: ServletContext resource [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff]
DEBUG ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Determined media type 'application/x-font-woff' for ServletContext resource [/resources/webjars/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff]
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Permissions:

```
$ cd ~/workspace/xxxxx/target/classes && ls -l . && ls -l META-INF && ls -l META-INF/services && ls -l properties && ls -l properties/common && ls -l properties/development
insgesamt 76
drwxrwxr-x 4 danny danny  4096 Nov 12 17:57 com
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny 19074 Nov 12 17:57 import.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny   519 Nov 14 22:16 logback.xml
drwxrwxr-x 3 danny danny  4096 Nov 12 17:57 META-INF
drwxrwxr-x 5 danny danny  4096 Nov 12 17:57 properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny  2215 Nov 12 17:57 tiles.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny  2444 Nov 12 17:57 wro.xml
insgesamt 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 danny danny 4096 Nov 12 17:57 services
insgesamt 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny 34 Nov 12 17:57 javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny 57 Nov 12 17:57 ro.isdc.wro.model.spi.ModelFactoryProvider
insgesamt 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 danny danny 4096 Nov 12 17:57 common
drwxrwxr-x 2 danny danny 4096 Nov 12 17:57 development
drwxrwxr-x 2 danny danny 4096 Nov 12 17:57 production
insgesamt 48
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny 737 Nov 12 17:57 application.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny  57 Nov 12 17:57 hibernate.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny  88 Nov 12 17:57 jdbc.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny 125 Nov 12 17:57 wro.properties
insgesamt 48
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny 142 Nov 12 17:57 application.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny  53 Nov 12 17:57 hibernate.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny  35 Nov 12 17:57 jdbc.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danny danny  17 Nov 12 17:57 wro.properties
```

Comment: Have you saw your folder permissions on the fisical path that the application is trying to reach?

Comment: No. But the rest of my webapp (Frontend) is working very well.

Comment: it could be an issue. So got to that folder and use `ls -l` to see permissions.

Comment: Where to find that folder when using tomcat7-maven-plugin?

Comment: yes it is on a linux machine

Comment: You can put your logging level to debug then you will see on the logs what is going on. Post the log after that

Comment: Strange thing. There is nothing that could indicate the problem within the log. So, let me try to understand. You are on a linux machine (as SO) using an IDE to program and test your application through  tomcat7-maven-plugin right?

Comment: Could you try and debug things from the browser, enabling firebug or the ie developer tool or whatever is applicable in your browser? See what requests get sent and what the responses are.

Comment: Mr. @flup did my next suggestion :) Also see where are your maven installed on your machine so you can find the directory where it is running the instance of tomcat7 with that folder you can check the permissions as I asked on very first comment.

Comment: Firebug returned `"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8080/admin/"` permissions are correct - The whole webapp wouldn't work if they were incorrect...

Comment: So as you coulnd find any solution yet. Do as follow, create a servlet without any security roles. Map it in your application (web.xml) then in its code, put the code to see the relative path  (fisical path) and then, after you see the path go to the folder and do a `ls -l` to see the permissions.

Comment: tomcat7-maven-plugin uses `target/tomcat` as configuration folder and `target/classes` as webapp folder. I've updated my question with the requested permissions. But as said: The whole webapp works out of the box. It's just the security thing which doesn't work (I guess it's not configured correctly)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the default authentication manager your rolenames must be prefixed with "ROLE_" to be matched.

Comment: Nope. `.roles("USER", "ADMIN");` in combination with `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")` results in 403 as well.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException: ROLE_USER cannot start with ROLE_ (it is automatically added)`

Comment: I will have a look at it tomorrow if there is no solution till then (I'm at CET, time to go to bed).

Comment: Ok try to give a solution in the next 22 hours (bounty ends then)

Comment: Back on this: Your admin is granted: 'Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin, ROLE_user' but you are requesting'@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")'. Is this a typo in your post or could you give it a try?

Comment: Yes, but you tried ROLE_ADMIN and your granted authority is ROLE_admin.

Comment: `.roles("USER", "ADMIN");` see first comment

Comment: No: Your user 'admin' is granted role "ROLE_admin" (mixed caps) but you are requiring @RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN") (all caps).

Comment: Btw.: Your code says .password(env.getProperty("adminPassword")).roles("user", "admin")

Comment: Yes, but after your answer I tried `.roles("USER", "ADMIN");` in combination with `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")` (ALL CAPS!)